# Rindler horizons as limits

Tags: unruh-effect

Consider a worldline $\bf{W}$ that accelerates at constant rate $\alpha$ only between $-t_0$ and $t_0$, and is otherwise inertial before $-t_0$ and after $t_0$. For all finite $t_0$ there is no Rindler horizon, hence no Unruh radiation should be expected for all finite $t_0$.

Is there something wrong with the above argument? If it is correct, it seems to me that Unruh radiation is topologically inaccessible from all finitely-accelerated worldlines, so inherently unphysical

Can $\bf{W}$ detect Unruh photons for finite values of $t_0$?

Comment: You do get radiation, but not in an exactly thermal form. See https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/531262/unruh-effect-for-finite-period-of-low-acceleration for further links.

Comment: It is not “worldline” itself that detects photons, but rather the detector, traveling along this worldline, that is one needs to specify explicitly some sort of mechanism for quanta detection. A simple, yet standard model is Unruh–DeWitt detector: two-level quantum system coupled to a scalar field.